# Search array of object from JSON data with PHP for a match and then update the matching keys data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to read a file of JSON data into PHP and search its array or objects for a matching anme value.  If a match is found I want to update the content of that  array objects data from a form POST data to update the item and then convert back to JSON and save to the json file.

```
$file = 'plugins.js';
$tmp_json_data = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($tmp_json_data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

foreach ($data as $key => $obj) {
    echo $obj->name;
    echo $obj->url;
    echo $obj->tag;
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Roundabout - Interactive, turntable-like areas
            [url] => http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/
            [tag] => slide
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Slides - Simple slideshow plugin for jQuery
            [url] => http://slidesjs.com/
            [tag] => slide
        )
)
```

How can I read my `$data` array in PHP and search for a matching object `name` that is equal to `$_POST['name']` and if a match is found, update the content of that array object?

Comment: Well you already got your foreach loop. Now you can just check for `$obj->name == $_POST["name"]` and if it matches you can update the object.

Comment: In your honor @Rizier123!

Comment: @AbraCadaver You couldn't do it without using `array_column()`?! :)

Comment: @Rizier123:  yes, but why?  I saw you were here.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an array (an object will work in PHP 7):

```
$data = json_decode($tmp_json_data, true);
$key  = array_search($_POST['name'], array_column($data, 'name'));
```

Then, I'm not sure what you mean by update, but:

```
$data[$key]['url'] = 'something new';
```